# AWS Batch Job Definition Creation: Role not Authorized

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-batch

I am looking to set up a Batch definition in AWS. I have made sure that the IAM role has the AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy permission.

However, when I try creating the job definition at the final step, I receive the error message: Error executing request, Exception : arn:aws:iam::{account_number}:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole role is not authorized.

Are there any other permissions required? I don't see any other necessities in the documentation.

I've tried creating different IAM roles with the same permissions but none of them seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create the job definition via cloudformation and it worked for me using the same iam roles.

When using the AWS console, I had the same role not authorized error.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem in the Oregon Region.
In other regions (e.g. Ohio Region, Tokyo Region) I was able to create job definitions from the dashboard without any problems.

Maybe you are experiencing problems in the Oregon Region.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).